# Access to Modified Closure (2)

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, closures

This is an extension of question from [Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure). I just want to verify if the following is actually safe enough for production use.

```
List<string> lists = new List<string>();
//Code to retrieve lists from DB    
foreach (string list in lists)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(delegate { MessageBox.Show(list); });
}
```

I only run through the above once per startup. For now it seems to work alright. As Jon has mentioned about counterintuitive result in some case. So what do I need to watch out here? Will it be ok if the list is run through more than once?

Comment: Congratulations, you're now part of the Resharper documentation.
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Access+to+modified+closure

Comment: This one was tricky but the above explanation made it clear for me: 
_This may appear to be correct but, in actual fact, only the last value of str variable will be used whenever any button is clicked. The reason for this is that foreach unrolls into a while loop, but the iteration variable is defined outside this loop. This means that by the time you show the message box, the value of str may have already been iterated to the last value in the strings collection._

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Prior to C# 5, you need to re-declare a variable *inside* the foreach - otherwise it is shared, and all your handlers will use the last string:

```
foreach (string list in lists)
{
    string tmp = list;
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(delegate { MessageBox.Show(tmp); });
}
```

Significantly, note that from C# 5 onwards, this has changed, and *specifically in the case of `foreach`*, you do not need to do this any more: the code in the question would work as expected.

To show this not working without this change, consider the following:

```
string[] names = { "Fred", "Barney", "Betty", "Wilma" };
using (Form form = new Form())
{
    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = name;
        btn.Click += delegate
        {
            MessageBox.Show(form, name);
        };
        btn.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        form.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Run the above **prior to C# 5**, and although each button shows a different name, clicking the buttons shows "Wilma" four times.

This is because the language spec (ECMA 334 v4, 15.8.4) (before C# 5) defines:

> `foreach (V v in x)` *`embedded-statement`* is then expanded to:
>
> ```
> {
>     E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
>     try {
>         V v;
>          while (e.MoveNext()) {
>             v = (V)(T)e.Current;
>              embedded-statement
>         }
>     }
>     finally {
>         … // Dispose e
>     }
> }
> ```

Note that the variable `v` (which is your `list`) is declared *outside* of the loop. So by the rules of captured variables, all iterations of the list will share the captured variable holder.

From C# 5 onwards, this is changed: the iteration variable (`v`) is scoped **inside** the loop. I don't have a specification reference, but it basically becomes:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

---

Re unsubscribing; if you actively want to unsubscribe an anonymous handler, the trick is to capture the handler itself:

```
EventHandler foo = delegate {...code...};
obj.SomeEvent += foo;
...
obj.SomeEvent -= foo;
```

Likewise, if you want a once-only event-handler (such as Load etc):

```
EventHandler bar = null; // necessary for "definite assignment"
bar = delegate {
  // ... code
  obj.SomeEvent -= bar;
};
obj.SomeEvent += bar;
```

This is now self-unsubscribing ;-p

Comment: If that's the case, the temporary variable will stay in memory until the app closes, as to serve the delegate, and it won't be advisable to do that for very huge loops if the variable takes up a lot of memory. Am I right?

Comment: It will stay in memory for the length of time that there are things (buttons) with the event. There is a way of un-subscribing once-only delegates, which I'll add to the post.

Comment: But to qualify on your point: yes, captured variables can indeed increase the scope of a variable. You need to be careful not to capture things you weren't expecting...

Comment: Could you please update your answer with respect to change in C# 5.0 spec? Just to make it a great wiki documentation regarding foreach loops in C#. There are already some good answers regarding change in C# 5.0 compiler treating foreach loops http://bit.ly/WzBV3L, but they aren't a wiki-like resources.

Comment: But I assume the `for` loop keeps its variable scoping in 5.0 and still needs the local variable workaround, is that correct?

Comment: @Kos yes, `for` is unchanged in 5.0