# Does RelayCommand, or passing an Action<T>, behave differently when the method is from an interface?

Tags: .net-3.5, delegates, action, relaycommand

I think this is my overall .NET inexperience speaking here, but I cannot figure out why this is happening to me.

My Model `ImportMany`s an interface called ISystemSetupEditor, and in this case I have a couple of parts that `Export` that interface.

In the application's ViewModel, I have a method that creates a menu, and iterates over the `IEnumerable<ISystemSetupEditor>` to populate the menu items, like so:

```
private ObservableCollection<WPFMenuItem> CreateSystemSetupItems()
{
    ObservableCollection<WPFMenuItem> menu = new ObservableCollection<WPFMenuItem>();

    foreach(ISystemSetupEditor editor in _model.SystemSetupEditors) {
        WPFMenuItem menuitem = new WPFMenuItem( editor.GetName());
        menuitem.Command = new RelayCommand( () => editor.ShowTool());
        menu.Add( menuitem);
    }

    return menu;
}
```

The problem is, when I click on **any** menu item, the ShowTool() for the last-enumerated ISystemSetupEditor-derived object always gets called.  It's as if the same reference is being stored by each RelayCommand.

I was hoping that someone could:

- explain why this is happening, or at least give me a keyword so I can look it up and figure it out on my own
- present possible solutions -- the only one I've come up with so far is to manage a separate Dictionary, where T,U would be able to resolve to the correct library so the right function can get called later on.

Comment: It might be that you should pass in a helper method that takes e.g the name of the editor.  That helper method can then search for the correct editor and call ShowTool() on it

Comment: @David: thanks, I will likely have to give that a try... it sounds basically like what I was proposing above with the Dictionary that keeps track of the association between a setup tool and possibly, its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats basically how closures and loops work in c#.

Take a look at good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512166/c-the-foreach-identifier-and-closures)

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks!  I knew I've read about that before, yet totally forgot about it.  I appreciate the link.