# System.Threading.Tasks in a for loop issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am tearing my hair off because of the following issue. I have this bit of code that loops through a list of objects and creates a processing task for each of them.

```
        IList<TileInfo> tiles = tileSource.Schema.GetTilesInView(extent, level);
        List<Task> renderingTasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (TileInfo info in tiles) {
            renderingTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(delegate {
                Console.WriteLine(Task.CurrentId +"Info object"+ info.GetHashCode());
                             }
                         })));
        }
```

This code prints:

```
1Info object36963566
2Info object36963566
3Info object36963566
4Info object36963566
5Info object36963566
6Info object36963566
7Info object36963566
8Info object36963566
9Info object36963566
10Info object36963566
11Info object36963566
12Info object36963566
...
```

As you can see, the problem is that the tasks seem to all have a reference to one object!

Why are the tasks all using only one object from the list?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try and add some more detail in a moment, but it's about closing over the variable. Change you code to:

Essentially what you need to do, is create a new variable inside the loop, equal to the single declaration outside the inner workings of the loop.

```
IList<TileInfo> tiles = tileSource.Schema.GetTilesInView(extent, level);
List<Task> renderingTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (TileInfo info in tiles) 
{
   TileInfo closingInfo = info;
   renderingTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(delegate {
                      Console.WriteLine(Task.CurrentId +"Info object"+ closingInfo.GetHashCode()); }})));
}
```

To Read more:

[The foreach identifier and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512166/c-sharp-the-foreach-identifier-and-closures)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`object36963566` must be last instance in your tiles list

This is because how the `foreach` works in current implementation of .Net. Although it will be fixed in future.

You need to read [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for understanding how foreach works in this case.

`Task.CurrentId +"Info object"+ info.GetHashCode()`

`info` in above code is referring to an item in the list `tiles`. The `delegate` you are creating will not use the item `info` was referring to when it(delegate) was created. Rather it will use the current value of `info`(value that info was pointing to when the method/delegate will actually run) which is obviously pointing to last item of the list. That's why you are getting this behaviour