# What am I doing wrong with my Thread Pools?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have daily reports I'm trying to collect en masse from a remote web service  my code looks like this:

```
    public static void ProcessEnMasse(System.DateTime fromDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);
        for (System.DateTime d = fromDate; d <= endDate; d = d.AddDays(1))
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(day => ProcessOneDay(d)));
        }
    }

    public static void ProcessOneDay(System.DateTime theDate)
    {
        Log.Debug(string.Format("Processing {0:yyyy-MM-dd}...", theDate));
        var thePackager = new DataPackager();
        thePackager.CreateDatabaseImportPackage(theDate, theDate, true, false);
    }
```

... when I look at the logs, I notice that several of the threads are processing the same date.  Why is this, and what do I need to do to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick and accurate diagnosis of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be mindful of closures (I will give a fuller explanation shortly)

Basically, your code should be this:

```
public static void ProcessEnMasse(System.DateTime fromDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);
        for (System.DateTime d = fromDate; d <= endDate; d = d.AddDays(1))
        {
            System.DateTime newD = d;
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
                (new System.Threading.WaitCallback(day => ProcessOneDay(newD)));
        }
    }
```

[Here is Jon Skeet's chapter on closures](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx)

The high level idea is that (in your original code) when you pass in `d`, it actually traps that variable and the compiled code will make that variable act as though it is a global shared variable. So, what happens is when you hit your next `for` step, `d` is updated in not only your loop, but in the function that you just passed it in to.

That is the high level, but I really advocate reading Jon Skeet's article as it is very well written.

[Here is another article](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained) if you are looking for more :)

Comment: Excellent.  I knew it had to be something simple.  I don't use threading that much, and thread pools less often, so this is definitely a "good-to-know".  I'm marking this as the answer as it is the most complete.

Answer (score 2):

All of your lambda expressions share the same `d` variable.

If one of the work items only starts after the initial thread ran `d = d.AddDays(1)`, it will use that date.

To fix this, declare a separate local variable inside the loop body and use that instead.

Comment: Regarding the fix - this is variable "closure" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512166/c-sharp-the-foreach-identifier-and-closures

Comment: @Reddog I will see if I can find the article, but I am pretty sure that either in 5.0, or maybe it is just slated for the next release after, but the foreach will not act the same

Comment: @JustinPihony: Yes; Eric Lippert said this was fixed in 5.  (but for for `foreach`, not `for`)

Answer (score 2):

You are "[capturing the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)".

To solve it:

```
for (System.DateTime d = fromDate; d <= endDate; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
     DateTime copy = d;
     System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            new System.Threading.WaitCallback(day => ProcessOneDay(copy)));
}
```

Or you can write it like this (note that `day` isn't used in the code above):

```
for (System.DateTime d = fromDate; d <= endDate; d = d.AddDays(1))
{         
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(day => ProcessOneDay((DateTime) day), d);
}
```