# Linq Expression snaphot an index value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

This problem is easiest described with code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int index = 0;
        var listOfExpressions = new List<ClassHoldingExpression>();
        listOfExpressions.Add(new ClassHoldingExpression((a) => a.Dict[index]));

        index++;
        listOfExpressions.Add(new ClassHoldingExpression((a) => a.Dict[index]));

        var dictClass = new ClassWithDict();
        dictClass.Dict[0] = "Test 1";
        dictClass.Dict[1] = "Test 2";

        foreach (var expr in listOfExpressions)
            Console.WriteLine((string)expr.Eval(dictClass));
    }
}


public class ClassWithDict
{
    public ClassWithDict()
    {
        Dict = new Dictionary<int, object>();
    }
    public Dictionary<int, object> Dict { get; set; }
}
public class ClassHoldingExpression
{
    private Expression<Func<ClassWithDict, object>> Expression { get; set; }

    public ClassHoldingExpression(Expression<Func<ClassWithDict, object>> expr)
    {
        Expression = expr;
    }

    public object Eval(ClassWithDict source)
    {
        return this.Expression.Compile().Invoke(source);
    }
}

//Output: 
//Test 2
//Test 2

//Desired:
//Test 1
//Test 2
```

Basically, I want to populate that dictionary with multiple values, and populate the list of `ClassHoldingExpression` with different expressions at specific indeces. However, it seems to look back and look for the *current* value of "index", instead of saving the current value into the expression. How can I force it to save the current *value* of `index` into the Expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a new variable that will hold the value that you want.

```
int index0 = 0;
var listOfExpressions = new List<ClassHoldingExpression>();
listOfExpressions.Add(new ClassHoldingExpression((a) => a.Dict[index0]));

int index1 = index0 + 1;
listOfExpressions.Add(new ClassHoldingExpression((a) => a.Dict[index1]));
```

If you need to do that in a loop, define a variable for each loop iteration before capturing it.

Answer (score -1):

looks like a closure issue.

```
foreach (var TMPexpr in listOfExpressions){
   var expr = TMPexpr ;  // take LOCAL copy
   Console.WriteLine((string)expr.Eval(dictClass));
}
```

[similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512166/c-sharp-the-foreach-identifier-and-closures)