# What is wrong with this class? (design wise)

Tags: c#, architecture

Following up from this question:
[designing application classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962175/designing-application-classes)

What is wrong (from a design point of view) with this class:

I'm trying to refactor this class and it's abstract base class (Logon) and the fact it's actually horrible design.  I wrote it myself (pretty much when I was a newbie).  I'm finding it hard to refactor and want some input on it?

```
 class NewUserLogon : Logon, ILogonNewUser, IDisposable
    {
        #region Member Variables

        System.Windows.Forms.Form _frm = new MainWindow();

        SQLDatabase.SQLDynamicDatabase sql;
        SQLDatabase.DatabaseLogin dblogin;
        LogonData lgndata;
        System.Security.SecureString securepassword;
        PasswordEncrypt.Collections.CreatedItems items;

        LogonEventArgs e = new LogonEventArgs();

        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        // for DI
        public NewUserLogon(PasswordEncrypt.Collections.CreatedItems items) : base (items)
        {
            this.items = items;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        public new void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public  bool? ReadFromRegistry(HashedUsername username, HashedPassword hashedpassword)
        {
            return RegistryEdit.ReadFromRegistry(username, hashedpassword);
        }

        public  bool WriteToRegistry(HashedUsername username, HashedPassword hashedpassword)
        {
            return RegistryEdit.WriteToRegistry(username, hashedpassword);
        }

        public override void Login(TextBox username, TextBox password)
        {
            base.Login(username, password);
            Login(username.Text, password.Text);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Protected Methods
        protected override void Login(string username, string password) // IS INSECURE!!! ONLY USE HASHES 
        {
            base.Login(username, password);

            if (_user is NewUserLogon) // new user
            {
                sql = new PasswordEncrypt.SQLDatabase.SQLDynamicDatabase();
                dblogin = new SQLDatabase.DatabaseLogin();
                lgndata = base._logondata;
                securepassword = new System.Security.SecureString();

                // Set Object for eventhandler
                items.SetDatabaseLogin = dblogin;
                items.SetSQLDynamicDatabase = sql; // recreates L
                items.Items = items;

                string generatedusername;

                // write new logondata to registry
                if (this.WriteToRegistry(lgndata.HahsedUserName, lgndata.HashedPsw))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Generate DB Password...
                        dblogin.GenerateDBPassword();

                        // get generated password into securestring
                        securepassword = dblogin.Password;

                        //generate database username
                        generatedusername = dblogin.GenerateDBUserName(username);

                        if (generatedusername == "Already Exists")
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Username Already Exists");
                        }

                        //create SQL Server database
                        try
                        {
                            sql.CreateSQLDatabase(dblogin, username);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                            e.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                            e.Success = false;
                            OnError(this, e);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        e.Success = false;
                        e.ErrorMessage = exc.Message;
                        OnError(this, e);
                    }
                    OnNewUserLoggedIn(this, e); // tell UI class to start loading... 
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Unable to write to Registry!", "Registry Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }

            else if (_user is ExistingUserLogon) // exising user
            {

               bool? compare = base._regRead;
               lgndata = base._logondata;

                if (compare == true)
                {
                   //Tell GUI to quit the 'busydialog' thread
                    OnMessage(this, e);
                    LogonFrm frm = LogonFrm.LogonFormInstance;

                   // tell user he already exists and just needs to login
                    // ask if user wants to logon straight away
                    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dlgres; 
                    dlgres = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Your login already exists, do you wan to login now?", "Login Exists", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                    if (dlgres == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        ExistingUserLogon existinguser = new ExistingUserLogon(compare, lgndata);
                        existinguser.Error += new ErrorStatus(frm._newuser_Error);
                        existinguser.loginname = username;
                        existinguser.LoginNewUser();

                        ///TELL GUI THAT USER LOGIN SUCCEEDED, THROUGH EVENT
                        e.Success = true;
                        OnNewUserLoggedIn(this, e);

                    }
                    else
                    {  
                        e.Success = false;
                        e.ErrorMessage = "Failed";
                        OnError(this, e);

                    }
                }

            }


        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Don't have time, so just one thing: Don't new the dispose function, mark it virtual in the base class and override it while not forgetting to call the base dispose function. In this case you wrote the base class yourself, but with other classes, you could introduce some memory problems ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class tries to do too many things. Try to separate different responsibilities into separate classes (eg database access and UI stuff).
And why are you instantiating a new Form at the beginning of your class and don't seem to use it further on?

Comment: Thanks for noticing the unused _frm variable... What would you do with the MessageBox.Show(); call in the middle of this class? Only use it in UI classes and create a helper to handle error messages?

Comment: Yup. Single Responsibility Principle. And lots of dependencies (new keywords) - difficult to test in isolation.

Comment: so on the dependencies, use IOC or DI or refactor into smaller classes?

Answer (score 2):

Your `protected Login` is way too long.

Answer (score 0):

Security should be a cross cutting concern, not a base class.  I don't know if you have aspect oriented programming techniques available to you, but extending a base class with security built into it seems like an abuse of inheritance to me.

Comment: so you mean do not let classes with security related stuff be inheritable?

Comment: No, I'm saying that I'd prefer adding security as aspects rather than using inheritance.