# Diffrence between windows services running own processes vs shared process

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am working on project where we have decided to split our background tasks (network, CPU and IO intensive) into three windows services.

Now the question is, whether we should host all three services into a single process or create three independent services with their own processes.

Windows Service project template allows multiple services to be created, when installed they'll create separate entries in Service Control Manager (SCM) and can be controlled independently. The benefit here is better code management and code reuse.

However, if there is any performance drawback, which is the primary reason why we're having multiple services in the first place, I'd rather let go this benefit.

Please advise.

Comment: What performance issues are you hoping either solution (3 additional processes vs 1 additional process vs whatever your existing setup is) will fix? Adding more IPC/threads competing for the same amount of CPU power would tend to drive performance down, not up.

Comment: how the services will communicate with each other ? by there any chance is ti possible to create multiple instance of single service like (network or IO)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, true, but doesn't apply in this case, how much CPU is used while it is downloading a file from network? it can certainly take care of CPU intensive task during that time. That said, the question here is to understand the difference between, svc1, svc2 and svc3 sharing a single process p.exe vs having own processes svc1 -> p1.exe, svc2 --> p2.exe, svc3 --> p3.exe. It is decided that we're going to have three services in either case.

Comment: @vijayparmar, they use database for coordination. It is kind of relay arrangement. When one service finishes downloading files, other service start processing them, once it is done, next service will start uploading them.

Comment: I generally prefer separate processes, so a fault in one service doesn't take the others down.

Comment: @StephenCleary That makes sense. However, is there any difference between the two approaches? Is it as good as having independent processes from performance or resource utilization point of view?

Comment: The single-process solution would use fewer resources.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to go for  Seperarte windows services created using topshelf or other technology hence they are independent of paltform

**Scalability** easly scalable as per need ,if one service is being used more then other, then that one service can be scale up by running multiple instance of same.

**parallel processing** as services are independent they can work in prallel hence performance improved.