# Delegate and dispatcher in a foreach loop can't access current item

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, dispatcher

I'm trying to implement a progress bar in WPF.  I am looping through a list of file paths (List) and performing some operations on the files.  I want to track the progress of the process but it is not working correctly.  In this case each time the method tagAndMoveFiles() is called it is called with the same item from the foreach list but it is called the proper number of times.  I'm not very good with delegates (obviously)...I've included all relevant code.  Thanks for your help. (uploadProgress is the progress bar)

---

```
        uploadProgress.Maximum = impJob.SourceFilePaths.Count;
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int progress = 0;
        foreach (string sourcefilepath in impJob.SourceFilePaths)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
            delegate()
            {
                    uploadProgress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
                    new Action(
                        delegate
                            {
                                tagAndMoveFiles(sourcefilepath, targetFolder, impJob, sourceFileProcessed);
                                uploadProgress.Value = ++progress;
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                            }
                        ));
            }
            ));
            t.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate is capturing the same instance each time around the loop. So you need to add a local variable inside the loop like this...

```
foreach(string sourcefilepath in impJob.SourceFilePaths)
{
    string x = sourcefilepath;
    ...
        {
            tagAndMoveFiles(x, ...
        }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You ran into this problem: [Access to Modified Closure (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304258/access-to-modified-closure-2)

Short: you need to have a local variable inside your `foreach` loop to capture the `sourcefilepath` and pass that to the delegate.