# How do I fix: Access to foreach variable in closure resharper warning?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm getting this ReSharper warning: **Access to foreach variable in closure. May have different behaviour when compiled with different versions of compiler**.

This is what I'm doing:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    // Warning underlines "item".
    <div>@Html.DisplayBooleanFor(modelItem => item.BooleanField)</div>
}
```

My extension is as follows:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayBooleanFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    bool value;

    try
    {
        var compiled = expression.Compile()(helper.ViewData.Model);
        value = Convert.ToBoolean(compiled);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        value = false;
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(value ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

Note this is working as expected but how can I avoid this warning?
I'll appreciate any help provided.

Comment: Why are you using `Expression<>` if all you do with it is call `.Compile()` on it? Why not use `Func<>` directly?

Comment: Why are you passing in an Expression at all instead of just a bool?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: It's helpful for me since I don't need to use an if on my view.

Comment: @KellyEthridge: Because I want to do a DisplayBooleanFor instead of DisplayBoolean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to Modified Closure (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304258/access-to-modified-closure-2)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A block scoped variable should resolve the warning.

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    var myItem = item;
    <div>@Html.DisplayBooleanFor(modelItem => myItem.BooleanField)</div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the warning, any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Esteban there's more on the JetBrains wiki [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Access+to+modified+closure) (which depending on your version of R# may be linked directly from the lightbulb menu as 'Why is ReSharper suggesting this?); see also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure?rq=1)

Comment: @Esteban That's the best explication I found so far : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907987/access-to-foreach-variable-in-closure

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to apply `JetBrains.Annotations.InstantHandleAttribute` attribute to `DisplayBooleanFor` method.