# Thread safe pass integer to Action with Task

Tags: c#, .net

The following code does not work as I expect it. What am I doing wrong? Output is different on every run. Is there a better way of doing this? Assume action does something more complex than what's below.

```
Action<int> action = (int m) =>
{
    if ((m % 2) == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Even");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Odd");
};

const int n = 10;
Task[] tasks = new Task[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action(i+1));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Um, why was this downvoted? I'm sure it's a duplicate, but it's a perfectly valid, well-posed question in my mind.

Comment: @Cameron: Upvoted it so its 0 again :-)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this question has been asked quite a few times before.  Also, a question's validity does not matter when it's a duplicate.

Comment: I did a lot searching before posting. Found some similar ones but not exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda in your loop is capturing a reference to the same `i` *variable* every time through the loop, not its *value*.

Change your loop to something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action(j+1));
}
```

Note that the output will still be different on every run, but you should get exactly five even and five odd outputs.

Comment: Related to answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Thanks Cameron. Great answer. And thanks for the link as well.

Comment: Thought I'd show this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907987/access-to-foreach-variable-in-closure. It's worth noting that the behavior you see here will vary on compiler version. On .net 4.5 you wouldn't have had this issue since they changed how the closures work