# C# Task Syncing

Tags: c#, multithreading, proxy, task

```
 private void checkProxies()
        {
            foreach(string x in proxyList)
            {
                Task<bool> task = CheckProxy.CheckProxyNonBlocking(x);
                Application.DoEvents();
                task.ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    if (!t.Result)
                        Application.DoEvents();
                    else
                    {
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            validTextBox.Text += x + "\n";
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to build a proxy checker with a multi-threaded design ,proxyList is a variable from the type of 'string[]'.

My question is , if the checking takes a lot of time, is the x I am passing to the function checkProxyNonBlocking is the same x I'm dealing with in continue with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C# 5 (or later) and a `foreach` loop then it should work the way you expect, and `validTextBox.Text += x + "\n"` will have the correct value of `x` for that loop iteration. However if you are using C# 4 or a `for` loop then you will get inconsistent results where `x` might (depending on timing) have a value from a later loop iteration.

For a full explanation, read [Access to foreach variable in closure warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907987/access-to-foreach-variable-in-closure-warning) and [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Comment: Only 2 of those tasks are really getting executed , do you have any idea why?

Comment: It looks like you aren't explicitly waiting for the tasks to complete. Is it possible that your app or test exists while the tasks are still running?

Comment: Yeah I just want to add it to the list once checking is done.