# WPF running multiple tasks (selenium webdrivers) parallely not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to run multiple windows of Chrome browser parallely. This works fine for 2 or sometimes 3 windows, but when I run 4 or more windows, browsers are opened but only one of them is running while others are just left blank.

Here is my code

```
IWebDriver[] driver = new IWebDriver[forms.Length];
initDriver();    // custom method to initialize driver array using ChromeDriver

...

List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
int i = 0;
foreach (string form in forms)
{
    actions.Add(() => OpenWebsiteAndTest(form, i));
    i++;
}

using (var collection = new BlockingCollection<int>())
{
    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
}

private void OpenWebsiteAndTest(string formName, int index)
{
    // below website is only opened in one of the browsers
    driver[index].Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.myurl.com");
    ...
    doTests(formName);    // custom method to automate the website and perform some tests
}
```

The problem is, `OpenWebsiteAndTest` method is executed for only one of the browser instances and the code inside it is never executed for other windows

I think I'm either doing something wrong, or either doing it in a bad way. I want my application to open up to 9 windows and execute them simultaneously as per client's need.

Comment: If you put tracepoints in `OpenWebsiteAndTest` to output the value of `index`, does the output show expected result of `1, 2, 3, 4...` etc? Or does it show all one number (or does it skip a couple numbers)?

Comment: Hi Vishal, was my reply helpful?

Answer (score 4):

Keith Stein mentioned the crux of the problem, all your indexes are the same.

If you check your List using breakpoint, you will see this.

Although a bit counterintuitive, this is how closure work.

Check the link below to learn more about closure.

[Access to foreach variable in closure warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907987/access-to-foreach-variable-in-closure-warning)

[Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

To make the program work, you need to create a copy of the variable in the loop, and then use this copy as the parameter.

```
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string form in forms)
        {
            int copy = i;
            actions.Add(() => OpenWebsiteAndTest(form, copy));
            i++;
        }
```