# multithreading behavior strange C#!

Tags: c#, multithreading

this is my app to excute a threading example, but the output is not as expected , anyone have any clue about that please

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
namespace OTS_Performence_Test_tool
{
    class Program
    {

        static void testThread(string    xx)
        {

            int count = 0;
            while (count < 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(xx );
                count++;

            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello to the this test app ---");

            for (int i = 1; i<=3; i++)
            {

                    Thread thread = new Thread(() => testThread("" + i + "__"));

                thread.Start();

            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

but the out but is

3__

3__

3__

3__

3__

3__

3__

3__

3__

3__

4__

4__

4__

4__

4__

what happens exactly anyone can explain please 
thanks

Comment: What is the expected output, and why do you expect it?

Comment: the expected is 1__ five times , 2__ five times , and 3__ five times , the order is not important

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[See Eric Lippert's excellent blog post on this issue.](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/)

This is being caused by access to a ["modified closure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304258/access-to-modified-closure-2).

Change your loop's body to this:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=3; i++)
{
    int j = i;  // Prevent use of modified closure.
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => testThread("" + j + "__"));

    thread.Start();
}
```

(Note that for a `foreach` loop, this was fixed in .Net 4.5, but it was NOT fixed for a `for` loop.)

Answer (score 4):

Closure. You must pretty much copy the variable in the thread for it to keep the current value,.

Wight now all threads read the variable i with whatever value they have at the moment they run - NOT with the value it had when thread.start was called for them.

Answer (score 1):

`testThread` is not called when you create the `Thread` objects within the for loop - the method is called whenever the thread is scheduled to run. And that might happen later.

In your case, the threads started running after the for loop ended - by that time, `i` was equal to 3. So `testThread` was invoked 3 times with the value `3`.