# Why the class instance value is corrupted in the multi-thread environment?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here is the simple code,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=> SimpleClass.Instance.weird.SetHello(i)));
            thread.Start();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}

interface IClass
{
    WeirdClass weird{ get; set; }
}

class SimpleClass : IClass {
    public static SimpleClass Instance = new SimpleClass();

    public WeirdClass weird{ get; set; }

    public SimpleClass()
    {
        weird= new WeirdClass();
    }
}

class WeirdClass
{
    public int hello;

    public void SetHello(int i)
    {
        this.hello = i;
        Console.WriteLine(this.hello);
    }
}
```

We could see the 'hello' value in WeirdClass is not correct in multi-thread, the value is just like a static instance, but it is not.

Maybe the magic happens on `SimpleClass.Instance.async`, so could anyone give me some explanation about that ? Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask] and be explicit. How is it "corrupted"? You do realize that you're working with one `WeirdClass` instance?

Comment: I'd also *strongly* advise against the use of `async` as an identifier, given that it's a contextual keyword...

Comment: Anyway you're accessing a closure, see [Access to Modified Closure (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304258/access-to-modified-closure-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upvoted your question since it brought me to some interesting research.

In the for loop assign the `i` variable to a temp `ii` and use `ii` in the thread initialization, like this:

```
var ii = i;
Thread thread = new Thread(
    new ThreadStart(()=> SimpleClass.Instance.async.SetHello(ii)));
thread.Start();
```

I've tested it with different configurations and different contexts (for example, put a random `Thread.Sleep` between `hello` assignment and `Console.WriteLine`).

What my solution gets is this: every thread has its own unique `i` and gets it written on the `Console` a single time.
But the numbers are not written in order, since **the threads don't start sequentially as you create them**.

Just a side-note: as @JonSkeet recommended, don't use `async` as identifier, it's a reserved word. Use instead `AsyncWeird`, `InnerClass`, `HelloContainer`, or whatever that is not an official C# token, otherwise your code becomes less clear.

**UPDATE - SOLUTION:**

This:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

That is, in both cases `i` is created outside the `for` loop, and so it is somehow shared between different cycles of the loop. If you check the link @CodeCaster provided, you'll see the same issue with the `foreach` loop with previous versions of C#.

If you declare the thread in a cycle with `i` as input, you're telling to the thread: *"ok, when you start, get the `i` value!"*. In that moment, `i` has the proper value, but the thread asks for `i` only when it's effectively started, so the value has already changed because in the meantime the main thread has already begun a new cycle of the loop and has already re-assigned the `i` for the next iteration.

Instead, if you create a temp variable `ii` *inside* the loop, it remains in that cycle and cannot be seen outside.

This is a demonstration of the whole game: try to declare `ii` *outside* of the loop... the behavior is again the incorrect one, that you showed with the `i` variable.

Comment: yes, your code gives me the correct result.... what's the difference...

Comment: You'll have to read [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) if you want to post a useful and correct answer.

Comment: @MK87: This behavior changed with new versions of the C# compiler.  Note that it's determined by the .NET compiler version used to build the project, it's not a runtime compatibility issue.