# Groovy Closures Vs C# Anonymous Method, Are they similar?

Tags: c#, groovy

I'm reading C#, and I came across the topic Anonymous method. As I know Groovy very well, I guess the Groovy Closures is very similar to C# Anonymous method. I checked the book's, online doc's the rules match. Like they wont execute until they have been invoked and so on.

Are these Groovy closures and C# Anonymous method are **equal**?

Or there are situation's where they behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be circumstances where they will behave differently.

C# anonymous methods can be "modified closures" in that their are circumstances where the execution context can be modified after the closure is created. See [Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure) and [ReSharper Warning - Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688465/resharper-warning-access-to-modified-closure) for a more thorough explanation.

I believe that in Groovy, "closures" give more guarantees on the execution context being copied.  However, it should be noted that my experience is in C#, and I have only limited exposure to Groovy.

Comment: C# closures are defined to behave that way, and they share that behaviour with many other languages. Claiming that this behaviour makes them "not true closures" is - IMHO - quite a strech, arguably even wrong.

Comment: @delnan - modified answer accordingly after reading the "Lexical environment" section on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29.

Comment: Leaving this answer for now, but I think I need to pull out a Groovy compiler and do some testing for verification.