# Why do local variable?

Tags: c#, linq, filter

resharper offers me to make this a local variable, and writes "access to modified closure"

```
if (filter != null)
{
    if (filter.CityId != 0)
    {
        ads = ads.Where(x => x.Ad.CityId == filter.CityId);
    }
    if (filter.BusinesCategoryId != 0)
    {
        ads = ads.Where(x => x.BusinessCategoryId == filter.BusinesCategoryId);
    }
}
```

Why do local variable filter?

Comment: Which local variable , `ads`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your query(Where(...)) is not being executed. I assume filter is obtained from a loop?

Linq query are not executed until they are used. so if you looped though a bunch of filters then started executing them later, the filter value would be wrong in the query.

A similar question : [Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure)
Also: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/273042

would need to see more code to 100% sure.

Comment: it is dangerous when there is a cycle? I do not cycle.

Comment: Closures can be modified without a loop.  The loop is the most common cause of unintentionally modified closure variables, but it's not the only cause.

Answer (score 3):

From how I understand this, Resharper will throw an error if you access a variable from a delegate (closure), and then modify the variable before you execute the delegate. This mostly happens if you access a for loop variable inside a delegate/lambda and execute it outside the loop. If your code is like:

```
foreach (filter in filters)
{
      if (filter != null)  {
            if (filter.CityId != 0)      {
                ads = ads.Where(x => x.Ad.CityId == filter.CityId);
            }
            if (filter.BusinesCategoryId != 0)      {
                ads = ads.Where(x => x.BusinessCategoryId == filter.BusinesCategoryId);
            }
      }
} 
return ads.ToList()
```

Then it will not behave like you'd expect it to. But if you execute the lambda expressions inside the loop scope then you would have no problem.

I wont explain why it behaves that way because a lot of people already explained it very well:

- [Eric Lippert's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)
- [ReSharper Warning - Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688465/resharper-warning-access-to-modified-closure)
- [Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach)

UPDATE:
To answer "Why do local variable?" is because the fix to the above problem is using a local variable (i.e., inside the loop) and using that in your lambda. That way you are closing over the different instances of the variable for each instance of the lambda.