# C# Threading issue - threads spawned with incorect parameters

Tags: c#

(environment: Azure websites. Own, non-shared 1 core instance)
I have the following loop which spawns needed number of threads.

```
    clientIds = comUtility.getAllSyncableClientIds();

    int numOfThreads = clientIds.Count();
    Thread[] exportThreads = new Thread[numOfThreads];

    foreach (int clientId in clientIds)
    {
        offset = offset + 10000; // time to wait
        exportThreads[threadId] = new Thread(() => RunExportToAzureOnItsOwnThread(pId, clientId, offset, threadId));
        exportThreads[threadId].Start();
        threadId++;
    }
```

Most of the time it seems to work fine. All threads spawn one after another and each thread has its own **offset** parameter which is just a wait time value called in each individual thread Thread.Sleep(offset); See the results from the log below:

[image]

HOWEVER, FOR SOME REASON, ONCE IN A WHILE some of the threads spawn with the same **thread number** and **offset value** even though the parameter **clientId** is supplied properly in the chronological order (see below).

[image]

What I do not understand is how could the ***foreach loop*** finish with only 1/2 of the functionality within the loop being correct - in this case the loop correctly fetches the next **clientId** but forgets to increase the **offset** value.

Thx.

Comment: You are capturing over a closure.  Create a local variable in the `foreach` loop for `offset` and send that into your thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Comment: For such a problem ReSharper will tell you "Access to the modified closure". This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688465/resharper-warning-access-to-modified-closure) contains more details

Comment: ..yes, but since the 'offset' scope is defined in the calling environment and (I am leaving it to the compiler to sort it out ) why would the offset value be the same only sometimes ?

Comment: ...what i mean is even though the 'offset' has been defined in the foreach object shouldn't the spawned thread object keep reference to the scope chain and preserve the offset value?