# long vs {0L}[0]

Tags: c#, multithreading, interlocked

In one of our old services I found such piece of code (comments are original):

```
long[] tasksCounter = {0};  //boxing for long counters
long[] errorsCounter = {0}; //boxing for long counters
```

Further in the code these "arrays" are used with [Interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=netframework-4.7.1) class: `Interlocked.Increment(ref errorsCounter[0])`, `Interlocked.Read(ref errorsCounter[0])` etc).

I wonder why did not the author use basicaly `long tasksCounter, errorsCounter`?

Probably this approach has benefits I don't know about?

It's probably worth mentioning that the variables are used in async lambda. When I change it to basic `long` Resharper plugin warns me with "Access to modified closure" and suggests to wrap it in array. I found couple of questions about it:

[Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure)

[ReSharper Warning - Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688465/resharper-warning-access-to-modified-closure)

Comment: Did the original author come from the Java world, which doesn't have `ref` arguments?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I don't know, he does not work here anymore...

Comment: I know a developer, who is otherwise quite talented, who likes using arrays to hold single items because *inaudible muttering*.  I think its just how they learned it in school and no one corrected them, so they've done it that way ever since and because it works, why stop?

Comment: So does your update answer your own question?

Comment: Guys check the update. Probably this was Resharper's suggestion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Probably. I am reading these answers and trying to understand whether this suggestion is important in my case.

Comment: But why wrap in array and not just create a copy in temp variable? I don't remember resharper ever suggested me to wrap into array in case of captured closure.

Comment: @Evk Check another my question. With that code example one of the latest Resharper versions does suggest me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194818/how-are-ref-variables-being-captured-in-closure