# c# foreach with Action.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, concurrency, delegates, action, invoke

Alright, so I'm having a bit of an issue here.
Here is the loop.

```
lock (ClientLocker)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("#WriteAll: " + sm.Header);
    foreach (Client c in Clients)
    {
        if (c.LoggedIn)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("#TryWriteTo[" + c.Id + "](" + sm.Header + ")");
            LazyAsync.Invoke(() => c.WriteMessage(sm));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is LazyAsync

```
public static class LazyAsync
{
    public static void Invoke(Action a)
    {
        a.BeginInvoke(a.EndInvoke, null);
    }
}
```

Each `Client` contains a `socket`, so I can't hardly `Clone` it.
The problem is, when I do the `Invoke` to `c.WriteMessage`, since the execution is delayed, it usually won't fire on the first couple in the list, and will sometimes actually only fire a whole bunch on the very last item.

I know this has to do with c being a reference that changes before `Invoke` actually gets called, but is there a way to avoid this?

Doing a general `for(int i=0 etc` loop doesn't seem to fix this issue.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Remember, can't `Clone` `Client`.

Comment: Someone asks this just about every day. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach/8899347#8899347 for some links and discussion about the issue.

Comment: I did a search, but didn't find anything. Not like I didn't try.

Comment: Indeed; this is a hard one to find. That is precisely why this question is asked again almost every day. Unless you actually get the "access to modified closure" warning from resharper, there's no reason why you would know what keywords to search on.

Comment: Yeah my trail for that ran out :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Captured Variable In Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-sharp-captured-variable-in-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy your `c` to local variable like this:

```
lock (ClientLocker)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("#WriteAll: " + sm.Header);
    foreach (Client c in Clients)
    {
        if (c.LoggedIn)
        {
            Client localC = c;
            Trace.WriteLine("#TryWriteTo[" + c.Id + "](" + sm.Header + ")");
            LazyAsync.Invoke(() => localC.WriteMessage(sm));
        }
    }
}
```

Do a web search for: "Access to modified closure" if you want to get more information.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like such an easy solution, and I feel a bit dumb that I didn't think of it. I guess I just assumed that the same thing would happen with the local variable as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion is right: the variable `c` is captured by the lambda expression, but not evaluated until later.

This flavor of error pops up whenever you make use of a loop variable within a lambda expression, since the loop variable is scoped outside the loop, and not with each iteration of the loop.

You can work around this by creating a new local variable in the `foreach` loop, assign `c` to it, and then pass that new local variable into the lambda expression:

```
lock (ClientLocker)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("#WriteAll: " + sm.Header);
    foreach (Client c in Clients)
    {
        if (c.LoggedIn)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("#TryWriteTo[" + c.Id + "](" + sm.Header + ")");

            Client copyOfC = c;
            LazyAsync.Invoke(() => copyOfC.WriteMessage(sm));
        }
    }
}
```

Here are a few related StackOverflow posts:

- [Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure)
- [Is there a reason for C#'s reuse of the variable in a foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach/8899347#8899347)
- [C# lambda, local variable value not taken when you think?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155691/c-sharp-lambda-local-variable-value-not-taken-when-you-think)

Comment: I appreciate the links, it'll be nice to read up on some more stuff. One of those grey lines where you're not sure what you're referencing :p

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `c` to a local variable and calling `LazyAsync.Invoke` on that, to avoid `c` being reassigned to by the `foreach` loop before the invoke happens.  When `LazyAsync.Invoke` does `c.WriteMessage`, it's calling `WriteMessage` on whatever `c` happens to now point to, not what it was when `LazyAsync.Invoke(() => c.WriteMessage(sm))` was evaluated

```
foreach (Client c in Clients)
{
    if (c.LoggedIn)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("#TryWriteTo[" + c.Id + "](" + sm.Header + ")");

        Client client = c;
        LazyAsync.Invoke(() => client.WriteMessage(sm));
    }
}
```