# C# Access to modified closure

Tags: c#, resharper

```
public virtual void OnRegistrationJoin(RegistrationJoinEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Mobile member in e.Team)
    {
        member.SendMessage(1161, "You join the {0}.", EventFullName);

        if (e.Team.Count > 1)
        {
            Joinees.Remove(member);
            member.SendMessage(1161, "Your team formation is:");

            int i = 0;

            foreach (Mobile parter in e.Team.Where(partner => partner != member).ToList())
            {
                member.SendMessage(1150, "{0}: {1}.", ++i, partner.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    Members.Add(e.Team);
}
```

I get "access to modified closure" warning by resharper, I was wondering what's so wrong with this code, since all I do in the inner loop is send a message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to Modified Closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure) and several others.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
e.Team.Where(partner => partner != member)
```

The variable `member` is a direct reference to the `member` variable in the outer scope. While you might not have a problem with this in the above code, it is problematic when you are running the code on multiple threads or if you aren't evaluating the lambda in the `Where` method right away (for example, using `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`).

The reason this is a problem is that C# generates a method to then pass as a delegate to `Where`. That method needs direct access to `member`. If you were to assign the reference to another variable like this:

```
var m = member;
// ...
e.Team.Where(partner => partner != m);
```

Then C# can "capture" that value in a construct called a "closure" and pass it to the generated method. This will ensure that when `member` changes, the value you expect it to be when you pass it to `Where` isn't changed.

Comment: +1: Ultimately the bigest problems that I see coming out of this for most people is deferred execution.

Comment: Easily fixed by doing var closureMember = member. And using closureMember in the LINQ.

Comment: @Femaref - but it's the changing reference that's the problem, not the changing instance.

Comment: Of course it is. But the behaviour of your `closureMember` will be exactly the same - each iteration, it will change to the current object. If he weren't using the query directly but deferred, only the last member of the foreach'ed sequence would be used.

Comment: Oh, you meant assigning `closureMember` outside the lambda. Of course, that will work. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, can you edit with a simple case example where this would actually become a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The part resharper complains about is `e.Team.Where(partner => partner != member).ToList()`, as the referenced `member` will be changed. In this case, this isn't a problem, but in other cases, this can be a problem.

Note: you don't have to use `ToList()`, which forces eager evaluation of the `IEnumerable<T>`. Simply iterate over `e.Team.Where(partner => partner != member)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `member.SendMessage`  could modify `member`

That's modifying a closed variable used in the lambda

Comment: Not really. The problem is the outer foreach loop which modifies the bound `member` variable in the lambda.