# Access to Modified Closure in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, closures

```
foreach(var category in categories) {
    a.AddRange(_db.Articles.Where(c => c.Categories.Contains(category)));
}
```

The code runs fine, yet I get a warning about "access to modified closure" in reference to `category` used in the lambda expression.

**Question:** Is the warning of any consequence in this circumstance?

Comment: see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach). it might help too.

Comment: Um, there's a dozen hits in SO for "[Access to Modified Closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure)", any one of which answers this question.

Comment: @RaymondChen There are, but they didn't address the lambda context is the only reason I asked. I understand the idea of closure, just wanted to see if it meant something more specific in the context of LINQ in this odd case.

Comment: c# 5 changes this behavior to make the category variable have the value in the current iteration and not the last value.
iomagazine.com/Articles/2012/11/01/More-Than-Just-Async.aspx?Page=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning here is because you are accessing the variable `category` inside the closure for the `Where` lambda.  The value `category` changes with every iteration and `Where` is delay executed hence it will see the current value of `category` vs. the value at the time the lambda was created.

In this case you are likely fine.  Even though `Where` is delay evaluated the `AddRange` method is prompt and will force the evaluation of `Where` to completion.  Hence the `Where` method will see the value of `category` it expects.

If you'd like to remove the warning though simply declare a local copy of the iteration variable and capture that instead.

```
foreach(var category in categories) {
  var localCategory = category;
  a.AddRange(_db.Articles.Where(c => c.Categories.Contains(localCategory)));
}
```

Comment: I think this was me forgetting something about foreach loops - the iteration variable `category` is technically outside the loop right? much like this pseudo code `int i; for (i <= 10) { i++; }`? if that's the case, I understand - `Where` could be evaluated after `category` had changed? Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that the "category" variable lives in closure and can be modified outside your LINQ expression.

Look at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure) for some explanation.