# Array of curried functions not acting properly

Tags: c#, lambda, closures, currying

I'm relatively new to C#, so if the answer to this question is obvious I apologise.

There's a portion of a program I am writing that stores an array of structs, and one of the elements of the struct is a curried function.

The following is the portion of code causing the problem (minimised as far as I am able)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CurryingProblem
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct Value
        {
            public Func<decimal> Output;
        }
        public static decimal AddOne(decimal value)
        {
            return value + 1;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Decimal> ThingsToAdd = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
            Dictionary<string, Value> ThingsToPrint = new Dictionary<string, Value>();

            ThingsToAdd.Add("One", 1.0m);
            ThingsToAdd.Add("Two", 2.0m);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Decimal> thing in ThingsToAdd)
            {
                Value value = new Value();
                value.Output = () => AddOne(thing.Value);
                ThingsToPrint.Add(thing.Key, value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(ThingsToPrint["One"].Output());
            Console.WriteLine(ThingsToPrint["Two"].Output());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output of this program is

```
2.0
3.0
```

But the actual output is

```
3.0
3.0
```

Any direction as to where I've gone wrong would be wonderful.

Comment: Really? Because my copy-and-paste produces `2.0` and `3.0`...

Comment: Yep, mine definitely produces the wrong values. I'm running Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5 SP1, if this ends up being version dependant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is similar to **[access to modified closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186189/access-to-modified-closure-in-lambda-expression)**. This [**article by Eric Lippert**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) explains it very well. You need to pass variable of local scope instead of passing loop thing.Value. Create a new variable and assign thing.Value to it so that local copy is passed.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Decimal> ThingsToAdd = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
        Dictionary<string, Value> ThingsToPrint = new Dictionary<string, Value>();

        ThingsToAdd.Add("One", 1.0m);
        ThingsToAdd.Add("Two", 2.0m);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Decimal> thing in ThingsToAdd)
        {
            Value value = new Value();
            Decimal d = thing.Value;
            value.Output = () => AddOne(d);
            ThingsToPrint.Add(thing.Key, value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ThingsToPrint["One"].Output());
        Console.WriteLine(ThingsToPrint["Two"].Output());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: This definitely works, thanks. I think this boils down to me not understanding the subtleties of scope.

Comment: I found this article very good for understanding http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx