# how should I make the following linq generic method returns distinct records?

Tags: linq, generics, distinct

when using the method below for an OR operation, I am getting back duplicate records. do I have to specify a custom IEqualityComparer? a simple distinct() does not work

```
internal static IQueryable<T> FilterEntity<T>(filters filters, IQueryable<T> entities)
    {
        if (filters.groupOp == "AND")
            foreach (var rule in filters.rules)
                entities = entities.Where<T>(
                    rule.field, rule.data,
                    (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse(typeof(WhereOperation), rule.op)
                    );
        else
        {
            //Or
            IQueryable<T> temp = (new List<T>()).AsQueryable();
            foreach (var rule in filters.rules)
            {
                var t = entities.Where<T>(
                    rule.field, rule.data,
                    (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse(typeof(WhereOperation), rule.op)
                    );

                    temp = temp.Concat<T>(t).AsQueryable();
            }
            entities = temp;
        }
        return entities;
    }
```

EDITED AFTER SUGGESTION FROM @usr below - This gives me the correct query in sql profiler (with a distinct) but this starts to look too convoluted - I wd like a cleaner solution

```
    internal static IQueryable<T> FilterEntity<T>(filters filters, IQueryable<T> entities)
    {
        if (filters.groupOp == "AND")
            foreach (var rule in filters.rules)
                entities = entities.Where<T>(
                    rule.field, rule.data,
                    (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse(typeof(WhereOperation), rule.op)
                    );
        else
        {
            //Or
            var t1 = entities.Where<T>(filters.rules[0].field,filters.rules[0].data,
                (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse(typeof(WhereOperation),filters.rules[0].op)
                );
            for (int i = 1; i<filters.rules.Count(); i++)
            {

                var t = t1.Where<T>(filters.rules[i].field, filters.rules[i].data,
                (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse(typeof(WhereOperation), filters.rules[i].op)
                );
              t1.Concat<T>(t).AsQueryable();
            }
           entities  = t1;
        }
        return entities.Distinct<T>();
    }
```

Comment: You can't use "new List<T>()" together with a LINQ query in almost all LINQ providers. This code is not doing what you want (although it will run fine). It is calling the database too often. It is not a real query.

Comment: its creating one query for each rule I use; only not doing a distinct; it is doing what I want - just not all the way; do you have a better way of implementing a multiple dynamic search? - I'll be glad to switch to it

Comment: Same issue when I write a separate filter class for each entity I have with List<SpecificEntity> instead of List<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to `Distinct()` or `IEqualityComparer`. It is the [modified closure gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure), that is: the loop variable `rule` must be copied in the loop body:

```
foreach (var rule in filters.rules)
{
    var rule1 = rule;
    // work with rule1 only.
```

You can follow Usr's advice by doing this:

```
IQueryable<T> temp = null;
    ....
    foreach (var rule in filters.rules)
    {
        var rule1 = rule;
        var t = entities.Where<T>(rule1.field, rule1.data,
            (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse(typeof(WhereOperation), rule1.op));

            if (temp == null)
                temp = t;
            else
                temp = temp.Union(t); // Union!!
    }
}
return temp;
```

I wonder if it solves your issue. Note the use of `Union` (which is an implicit `Distinct`). If it does not solve your issue I think there is some code invisible to us (e.g. in your `WhereOperation`) that interferes.

Comment: OK, can you give some detail? No difference, exceptions?

Comment: duplicate records returned for records that meet more than 1 condition specified in the OR operation (I am using this for a client side grid) - no exceptions

Comment: Right. Well, the modified closure issue stands anyway. Is `entities` a simple collection of entities, or does it already have `Where`s applied to it before it enters `FilterEntity`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't start with a `List<T>` to start your query. Start with the first "`t`". That way you will get only one query which is executing on the server. Use Union instead of Concat to get distinct results.

Comment: union doesnt work either - can you show me how to start without List<T>

Comment: added above the 1st solution I implemented to start with the 1st t; result is what I need, looking at the sql profiler, but this is starting to look like a hack; can it be improved?

Comment: You could remove some redundancies from the code but it is ok. You got it right. Glad it's working for you.