# How do I return a list of Distinct Words using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The goal is to sort through a text (i.e. a speech) and output a list of the distinct words in the speech to a textbox.  I have read through a lot of tips on the boards and played around a lot but at this point am at that point where I am more confused then when I started.  Here is my code

```
   private void GenerateList(string[] wordlist)
    {
       List<string> wordList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.Length; i++)
        {
            wordList.Add(wordlist[i]);
        }

        var uniqueStr = from item in wordList.Distinct().ToList()
                        orderby item
                        select item;


        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueStr.Count(); i++ )
        {
            txtOutput.Text = uniqueStr.ElementAt(i) + "\n";
        }

    }
```

At this point I am getting a return of one word.  For the text I am using (the gettysburg address) it is the word "year" and it is the only instance of that word in the text.

I am passing the function each individual word loaded into a string array that is then put into a list (which may be redundant?).

Comment: Watch carefully at the line `txtOutput.Text = uniqueStr.ElementAt(i) + "\n"`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this does what you need in a simple and efficient manner (using .Dump() from LINQPad)

```
void Main()
{
    // can be any IEnumerable<string> including string[]
    var words = new List<string>{"one", "two", "four", "three", "four", "a", "z"};

    words.ToDistinctList().Dump();

    // you would use txtOutput.Text = words.ToDistinctList()
}

static class StringHelpers
{
    public static string ToDistinctList(this IEnumerable<string> words)
    {
        return string.Join("\n", new SortedSet<string>(words));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few tips regarding your question:

- There is no reason to turn the array into list, because LINQ extension methods are defined on `IEnumerable<T>`, which is implemented by both the array and the list
- Make sure that all letters are in the same case - use ToLower, for instance
- You are overwriting txtOutput.Text in every iteration. Instead of setting the new value, append new part to the existing value

Here is the simple piece of code which produces the output you wanted:

```
IEnumerable<string> distinct =
    wordList
    .Select(word => word.ToLower())
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(word => word);

txtOutput.Text = string.Join("\n", distinct.ToArray());
```

On a related note, here is a very simple LINQ expression which returns distinct words from a text, where the whole text is specified as one string:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoWords(this string text)
{

    string pattern = @"\b[\p{L}]+\b";

    return
        Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
            .Cast<Match>()                          // Extract matches
            .Select(match => match.Value.ToLower()) // Change to same case
            .Distinct();                            // Remove duplicates

}
```

You can find more variations of regex pattern for the same problem here: [Regex and LINQ Query to Split Text into Distinct Words](http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=hints/split-text-into-words)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I'd simplify your code, as well as achieve what you want to achieve.

```
private void GenerateList(string[] wordlist)
{
   List<string> wordList = wordlist.ToList(); // initialize the list passing in the array


    var uniqueStr = from item in wordList.Distinct().ToList()
                    orderby item
                    select item;


    txtOutput.Text = String.Join("\n", uniqueStr.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, `wordList` is a parameter name, you can't redefine it as a variable.  Also, materializing `wordList` is inefficient, as `wordList` is an array, it's *already* a materialized list.  The call to `ToList` in the query is also unnecessary, materializing the list for no good reason (as it's ordered after that and that ordering is not done in-list).

Comment: @casperOne look again.  The variable is `wordlist` passed in, whereas the local variable is `wordList` with a capital `L`.  This is his **original** code, just shortened and does not justify a -1 vote.

Comment: Note: votes do not have to be justified and are anonymous.  That said it will compile, but the statements about the inefficiencies are still correct.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fact that the [`StringBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) has a fluent interface along with LINQ to simplify this greatly.

First, you can create the `StringBuilder` and concatenate all of the words into the same instance like so:

```
// The builder.
var builder = new StringBuilder();

// A copy of the builder *reference*.
var builderCopy = builder;

// Get the distinct list, order by the string.
builder = wordList
    // Get the distinct elements.
    .Distinct()
    // Order the words.
    .OrderBy(w => w).
    // Append the builder.
    Select(w => builderCopy.AppendLine(word)).
    // Get the last or default element, this will
    // cycle through all of the elements.
    LastOrDefault();

// If the builder is not null, then assign to the output, otherwise,
// assign null.
txtOutput.Text = builder == null ? null : builder.ToString();
```

Note, you don't have to actually materialize the list, as `wordList` is *already* a materialized list, it's an array (and as a side note, typed arrays in C# implement the [`IList<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)).

The [`AppendLine` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx) (and most of the methods on `StringBuilder`) return the instance of the `StringBuilder` that the operation was performed on, which is why the [`LastOrDefault` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx) call works; simply call the operation and return the result (each item returned will be the same reference).

The `builderCopy` variable is used to avoid [access to a modified closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235459/50776) (it never hurts to be safe).

The null check at the end is for the case where `wordList` doesn't contain any elements.  In this case, the call to `LastOrDefault` will return null.