# Variable caching

Tags: c#, multithreading

Why in this part of code `complete` is cached?

```
static void Main()
{
  bool complete = false; 
  var t = new Thread (() =>
  {
    bool toggle = false;
    while (!complete) toggle = !toggle;
  });
  t.Start();
  Thread.Sleep (1000);
  complete = true;
  t.Join();        // Blocks indefinitely
}
```

but in this part it isn't?

```
static void Main()
{
  bool complete = false;
  bool toggle = false; 
  var t = new Thread (() =>
  {
    while (!complete) toggle = !toggle;
  });
  t.Start();
  Thread.Sleep (1000);
  complete = true;
  t.Join();  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing unsynchronized data sharing across threads. Sirens should now go off.

As I understand the memory model the JIT is allowed to read `complete` once and store it in a register. For that reason the update from Main never becomes visible.

As for fixing this, the simplest way is to wrap a lock around accesses to `complete`. You could also use `Thread.VolatileRead` and `Thread.VolatileWrite`.

Comment: The question not about fixing. **Why** in first snippet `compare` is cached but in second isn't?

Comment: Ok, I missed that point. I guess this is because in the 2nd snippet toggle is a heap write while in the 1st it is a local variable write. Heap stores prevent certain reorderings. They prevent sometimes "caching" across them. Either this is formally guaranteed by the x86/.NET memory model or it is just a JIT optimizer quirk/property.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be sure caching will happen on all architectures as above, or even that it will always happen as above in multiple runs of the program.

It *could be* because in the second case the lambda is modifying the closure, while in first it is only accessing the closure. Of course this is only a wild guess.

More importantly though, **there are no guarantees about when caching *will* be done, memory boundary only specifies when the thread will *not* use cached value**.

Bottom line, you cannot rely on caching to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Both samples complete in my case, but you're lambda/delegate can be compile differently in different compilers, which could be the problem.

You delegate are accessing a modified closure, which can cause a bunch of problems and you have apparently found one. Take a look at the answer provided by Jon Skeet here, [Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure), it is not exactly the same problem, but the reason described here works in you case too.