# LINQ to Objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have an object, built upon a XML schema and want to use LINQ to get the data out of it
which I'm interested in :)

The structure look like the following example :

```
SimulationStep [1..n]
   - EnvironmentStep [1]
       - Events [0..n]
           - ResultingStateChanges [0..n]
               - Objects [1]
                   - Object[0..n]
```

each "Object" (the last one in that class chain) has an attribute x, y and z, meaning the position of this object
in 3D space. Theres also an ID which is used to identify each object.

Now I want to collect all (x,y,z) triplets for each SimulationStep for the object which equals the given ID.

I tried it this way :

```
for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; i++)
{
    var events = from c in log.SimulationStep[i].EnvironmentSimulatorStep.EnvSimInputEvent
                        from d in c.ResultingStateChanges
                        from e in d.Agents.Agent
                       where e.id == id
                       select new { c.occurrenceTime, o = new Vector3((float)e.x, (float)e.y, (float)e.z) }
}
```

but all I get with this one, is the result (x,y,z) of SimulationStep 0. But I want a list with the positions
in each step. This way :
For example....

```
SimStep[0] - (0,0,0)
SimStep[1] - (5,0,0)
SimStep[2] - (10, 7, 0)
```

Comment: why not use XDocument it allows you to query XML data

Comment: @VincentDagpin: But i'm in LINQ now.

Comment: @Sandy There is a [Linq2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Comment: @Aron: I'm not much exp in that.

Comment: Also from a very high level, without actually seeing your code it looks to be a [Access to Modified Closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure) issue. One needs to be EXTREMELY careful when mixing for loops with LinQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope i got your ques.

Try this:

//Code

```
var events = from s in log.SimulationStep
                        from c in s.EnvironmentSimulatorStep.EnvSimInputEvent
                        from d in c.ResultingStateChanges
                        from e in d.Agents.Agent
                        where e.id == id
                        select new { 
                                     c.occurrenceTime, 
                                     o = new Vector3((float)e.x, 
                                     (float)e.y, 
                                     (float)e.z) 
                                    }
```

Comment: Assuming that log.SimulationStep exposes IEnumerable<T> then this would be the way I would go.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing the code I can't tell what type log.SimulationStep is. If it is indeed a Access Closure Modified issue, the way to fix this is simply to roll the for loop into our LinQ statement (or just use for loops all the way).

```
var events = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, stepCount)
             let simulationStep = log.SimulationStep[i]
             from c in simulationStep.EnvironmentSimulatorStep.EnvSimInputEvent
             from d in c.ResultingStateChanges
             from e in d.Agents.Agent
             where e.id == id
             select new { 
                          c.occurrenceTime, 
                          o = new Vector3((float)e.x, 
                          (float)e.y, 
                          (float)e.z) 
                        }
```