# Use array of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to threads so it might be an easy one for you, but I've spent some hours trying to figure it out.

Let's say I have a function

```
public double Gain(List<int> lRelevantObsIndex, ushort uRelevantAttribute)
```

which needs some time to finish, but is a read only func.

I have an array of ushort[] values, and I want to get the ushort value that achieves the minimum value of the Gain function.

Here is what I've got so far, but it's not working:

**lRelevantObsIndex** is a read only index.

**lRelevantAttributes** is the list of ushort values.

```
        //Initialize the threads
        double[] aGains = new double[lRelevantAttributes.Count];
        Thread[] aThreads = new Thread[lRelevantAttributes.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < lRelevantAttributes.Count; i++)
        {
            aThreads[i] = new Thread(() => aGains[i] = Gain(lRelevantObsIndex, lRelevantAttributes[i]));
            aThreads[i].Start();
        }

        //Join the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < lRelevantAttributes.Count; i++)
            aThreads[i].Join();

        //The easy part - find the minimum once all threads are done
        ushort uResult = 0;
        double dMinGain = UInt16.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < lRelevantAttributes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (aGains[i] < dMinGain)
            {
                dMinGain = aGains[i];
                uResult = lRelevantAttributes[i];
            }
        }

        return uResult;
```

I know this is a simple multithreading question - but still need your brains since I'm new to this.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say it's "not working"? In what way is it not working? What is the behavior?

Comment: @dvnrrs, sure, it throws an exception in the first for loop.
it's trying to access array[i] and i is set to 30.
I guess it happens because of bad use of threads.

Comment: OK, yep, that is the result of the "access to modified closure" problem described in the answers below.

Comment: What you actually need is more like `Parallel.ForEach(lRelevantAttributes, ...)`. I doubt that creating separate threads is economical here (did you measure anything?). It certainly is the hard way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but it is *a* problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lRelevantAttributes.Count; i++)
{
    aThreads[i] = new Thread(() => aGains[i] = Gain(lRelevantObsIndex, lRelevantAttributes[i]));
    aThreads[i].Start();
}
```

When a lambda refers to a loop variable, the binding is delayed, so that when your lambda actually runs, it takes the value of `i` *at the time the lambda runs*, not the value it had when the lambda was created. To fix this, declare a secondary variable inside the loop, and use that in the lambda:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lRelevantAttributes.Count; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    aThreads[i] = new Thread(() => aGains[j] = Gain(lRelevantObsIndex, lRelevantAttributes[j]));
    aThreads[i].Start();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This one is somewhat tricky: your `for` loop uses a modified value here (a so-called [*access to modified closure*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/235455/335858))

```
for (int i = 0; i < lRelevantAttributes.Count; i++)
{
    aThreads[i] = new Thread(() => aGains[i] = Gain(lRelevantObsIndex, lRelevantAttributes[i]));
    aThreads[i].Start();
}
```

At the time the thread starts, `i` will be different in your lambda, accessing a wrong item. Modify your loop as follows:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < lRelevantAttributes.Count; ii++)
{
    var i = ii; // Now i is a temporary inside the loop, so its value will be captured instead
    aThreads[i] = new Thread(() => aGains[i] = Gain(lRelevantObsIndex, lRelevantAttributes[i]));
    aThreads[i].Start();
}
```

This will fix the problem, because lambdas will capture the current value of the temporary variable `i` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: This is exactly what the problem is; I've hit this one more than I care to admit. Remember folks - lambdas aren't evaluated in your loops, they close over any variables and are evaluated when you actually invoke them; in this case, on some set of background threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same on [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        List<Task<int>> tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5) //- it's equivalent how many threads
                                          .Select(x => Task.Run(() => DoWork(x)))
                                          .ToList();
        int[] result = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result; //- Join threads

        result.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    private int DoWork(int taskId)
    {
        return taskId;
    }
```

Result output:

```
3
0
1
2
4
```