# IndexOutOfRangeException exception when using tasks in for loop in C#

Tags: c#, loops, task

I am trying to use tasks in a for loop, but I am getting really strange exception! here is my code:

```
        Task[] tasks = new Task[strarrFileList.Length];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < strarrFileList.Length; ii++)
        {
            tasks[ii] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => mResizeImage2(ii, strarrFileList[ii], intLongSide, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Here is the error:

**An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in mCPanel.exe but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

So basically ii becomes equal to strarrFileList.Length which shouldn't! Does anyone have an explanation/solution for this?

Comment: your iterating variable may be updating inside the mResizeImage2 method

Comment: no, it is not updating anywhere else!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try copying ii to a local variable inside the for loop.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[strarrFileList.Length];
for (int ii = 0; ii < strarrFileList.Length; ii++)
{
    var currentIndex = ii;
    tasks[currentIndex] = Task.Run(() => mResizeImage2(currentIndex, strarrFileList[currentIndex], intLongSide, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

This is needed because you are accessing a modified closure. For example, since Task.Run() will not run right away, and you are simply just passing ii to it (w/out copying it locally), the value of ii may change when the ThreadPool does decide to run that particular Task. More info, see [Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure)

Comment: Thank you, an explanation would also be great!

Comment: could you please explain how this is solving the issue?