# Why am I getting different a different output when Asynchronous?

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

I have the folowing code writing to a textbox:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
{
    textBox1.Text += String.Format("Writing Line {0}{1}", ii + 1, System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I get the expected output off:

```
Writing Line 1
Writing Line 2
Writing Line 3
Writing Line 4
Writing Line 5
```

However when I update asyncornusly or from another thread as found here: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?lq=1)

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
{
    textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += String.Format("Writing Line {0}{1}", ii + 1 , System.Environment.NewLine)));
}
```

I get

```
Writing Line 5
Writing Line 5
Writing Line 5
Writing Line 5
Writing Line 5
```

The last line is printed 5 times where I expect the output to match the single-thread synchronous output?

What do I need to change to match the first output from the second thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `ii` is treated as begin defined outside the loop. It's compiled as if it looks like this:

```
int ii;
for (ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
{
    textBox1.Text += String.Format("Writing Line {0}{1}", ii + 1, System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Because of this your lambda is capturing the shared variable, not the unique instance of the value. You need to make a copy within the loop:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
{
    int localCopy = ii;

    textBox1.Text += String.Format("Writing Line {0}{1}", localCopy  + 1, System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

This use to be a problem with the `foreach` statement, too. In C# 5 they changed the behaviour of foreach so that the variable is treated as being declared within the body of the `foreach`, so the capture will work correctly. Because of this you could write:

```
foreach(int ii in Enumerable.Range(0,5))
{
    textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += String.Format("Writing Line {0}{1}", ii + 1 , System.Environment.NewLine)));
}
```

The important point here is that `for` and `foreach` behave differently in how they capture. With `for` the variable is deemed to be outside the loop, with `foreach` it is deemed to be within (and therefore safe to capture).

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are referencing the loop variable `ii` inside an asynchronous action. By the time the action is called, the loop has already finished, and the value of `ii` is 4. That is why you get all fives (i.e. 4+1) in the asynchronous version.

Making a temporary for `ii` would fix the problem:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {
    var iii = ii;
    textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += String.Format("Writing Line {0}{1}", iii + 1 , System.Environment.NewLine)));
}
```

This error is caused by access to modified closure. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/235455/335858) for more information on it.

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I tried doing something like that, but I used a variable outside the loop instead of new variable for every loop iteration. I feel like such an idiot. Thank you again.

Comment: @MichaelElkin In all fairness, this is an extremely tricky issue to spot when you see it for the first time. In fact, I am surprised that C# compiler did not fix this automatically from the start. The issue is so prevalent that Microsoft has finally decided to fix it in C# 5.0.