# Test helper for expected events sequence reporting duplicate events

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, lambda, anonymous-function

I have a helper method for my unit tests that asserts that a specific sequence of events were raised in a specific order. The code is as follows:

```
public static void ExpectEventSequence(Queue<Action<EventHandler>> subscribeActions, Action triggerAction)
{
    var expectedSequence = new Queue<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < subscribeActions.Count; i++)
    {
        expectedSequence.Enqueue(i);
    }

    ExpectEventSequence(subscribeActions, triggerAction, expectedSequence);
}

    public static void ExpectEventSequence(Queue<Action<EventHandler>> subscribeActions, Action triggerAction, Queue<int> expectedSequence)
    {
        var fired = new Queue<int>();
        var actionsCount = subscribeActions.Count;

        for(var i =0; i< actionsCount;i++)
        {
            subscription((o, e) =>
                {
                    fired.Enqueue(i);
                });
        }

        triggerAction();

        var executionIndex = 0;

        var inOrder = true;

        foreach (var firedIndex in fired)
        {

            if (firedIndex != expectedSequence.Dequeue())
            {
                inOrder = false;
                break;
            }

            executionIndex++;
        }

        if (subscribeActions.Count != fired.Count)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Not all events were fired.");
        }

        if (!inOrder)
        {
            Assert.Fail(string.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                "Events were not fired in the expected sequence from element {0}",
                executionIndex));
        }

    }
```

Example usage is as follows:

```
    [Test()]
    public void FillFuel_Test([Values(1, 5, 10, 100)]float maxFuel)
    {
        var fuelTank = new FuelTank()
        {
            MaxFuel = maxFuel
        };

        var eventHandlerSequence = new Queue<Action<EventHandler>>();

        eventHandlerSequence.Enqueue(x => fuelTank.FuelFull += x);

        //Dealing with a subclass of EventHandler
        eventHandlerSequence.Enqueue(x => fuelTank.FuelChanged += (o, e) => x(o, e));

        Test.ExpectEventSequence(eventHandlerSequence, () => fuelTank.FillFuel());
    }
```

And the code under test:

```
    public float Fuel
    {
        get
        {
            return fuel;
        }
        private set
        {
            var adjustedFuel = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(value, MaxFuel));

            if (fuel != adjustedFuel)
            {
                var oldFuel = fuel;

                fuel = adjustedFuel;

                RaiseCheckFuelChangedEvents(oldFuel);
            }
        }
    }

    public void FillFuel()
    {
        Fuel = MaxFuel;
    }

    private void RaiseCheckFuelChangedEvents(float oldFuel)
    {
        FuelChanged.FireEvent(this, new FuelEventArgs(oldFuel, Fuel));

        if (fuel == 0)
        {
            FuelEmpty.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else if (fuel == MaxFuel)
        {
            FuelFull.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        if (oldFuel == 0 && Fuel != 0)
        {
            FuelNoLongerEmpty.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else if (oldFuel == MaxFuel && Fuel != MaxFuel)
        {
            FuelNoLongerFull.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

So the test expects `FuelFilled` to be fired before `FuelChanged` but in actuality `FuelChanged` is fired first, which fails the test.

However my test is instead reporting that `FuelChanged` is being fired twice, but when I step through the code it is clear that `FuelFilled` is fired after `FuelChanged` and `FuelChanged` is only fired once.

I assumed that it was something to do with the way lambdas work with local state, maybe the for loop iterator variable was only ever set to the final value, so I replaced the for loop with this:

```
        var subscriptions = subscribeActions.ToList();

        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            subscription((o, e) =>
                {
                    var index = subscriptions.IndexOf(subscription);
                    fired.Enqueue(index);
                });
        }
```

However the result is the same, fired contains {1;1} instead of {1;0}.

Now I'm wondering if the same lambda is being assigned to both events instead of using the different subscription / index state. Any ideas?

**Update:** I was unable to get success with either answer posted so far (same as my initial results), despite their similarities to my actual code, so I presume the issue is located elsewhere in my `FuelTank` code. I've pasted the full code for `FuelTank` below:

```
public class FuelTank
{
    public FuelTank()
    {

    }

    public FuelTank(float initialFuel, float maxFuel)
    {
        MaxFuel = maxFuel;
        Fuel = initialFuel;
    }

    public float Fuel
    {
        get
        {
            return fuel;
        }
        private set
        {
            var adjustedFuel = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(value, MaxFuel));

            if (fuel != adjustedFuel)
            {
                var oldFuel = fuel;

                fuel = adjustedFuel;

                RaiseCheckFuelChangedEvents(oldFuel);
            }
        }
    }

    private float maxFuel;

    public float MaxFuel
    {
        get
        {
            return maxFuel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("MaxFuel", value, "Argument must be not be less than 0.");
            }
            maxFuel = value;
        }
    }

    private float fuel;

    public event EventHandler<FuelEventArgs> FuelChanged;

    public event EventHandler FuelEmpty;

    public event EventHandler FuelFull;

    public event EventHandler FuelNoLongerEmpty;

    public event EventHandler FuelNoLongerFull;

    public void AddFuel(float fuel)
    {
        Fuel += fuel;
    }

    public void ClearFuel()
    {
        Fuel = 0;
    }

    public void DrainFuel(float fuel)
    {
        Fuel -= fuel;
    }

    public void FillFuel()
    {
        Fuel = MaxFuel;
    }

    private void RaiseCheckFuelChangedEvents(float oldFuel)
    {
        FuelChanged.FireEvent(this, new FuelEventArgs(oldFuel, Fuel));

        if (fuel == 0)
        {
            FuelEmpty.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else if (fuel == MaxFuel)
        {
            FuelFull.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        if (oldFuel == 0 && Fuel != 0)
        {
            FuelNoLongerEmpty.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else if (oldFuel == MaxFuel && Fuel != MaxFuel)
        {
            FuelNoLongerFull.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

`FuelEventArgs` looks like this:

```
public class FuelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public float NewFuel
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public float OldFuel
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public FuelEventArgs(float oldFuel, float newFuel)
    {
        this.OldFuel = oldFuel;
        this.NewFuel = newFuel;
    }
}
```

The `FireEvent` extension method is looks like this:

```
public static class EventHandlerExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fires the event. This method is thread safe.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handler"> The handler. </param>
    /// <param name="sender">  Source of the event. </param>
    /// <param name="args">    The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data. </param>
    public static void FireEvent(this EventHandler handler, object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var handlerCopy = handler;

        if (handlerCopy != null)
        {
            handlerCopy(sender, args);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fires the event. This method is thread safe.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of event args this handler has. </typeparam>
    /// <param name="handler"> The handler. </param>
    /// <param name="sender"> Source of the event. </param>
    /// <param name="args"> The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data. </param>
    public static void FireEvent<T>(this EventHandler<T> handler, object sender, T args) where T : EventArgs
    {
        var handlerCopy = handler;

        if (handlerCopy != null)
        {
            handlerCopy(sender, args);
        }
    }
}
```

The full test code can be found above in the question, there is no other code called during test execution.

I am using NUnit test framework via the Unity Testing Tools plugin for the Unity3D engine, .NET version 3.5 (ish, it's closer to Mono 2.0, I believe), and Visual Studio 2013.

**Update 2:**

After extracting the code and tests to their own project (outside of the Unity3D ecosystem) all tests run as expected, so I'm going to have to chalk this one up to a bug in the Unity -> Visual Studio bridge.

Comment: Interesting question... I've tried to reproduce your situation by using NUnit (I am unsure which UnitTest toolkit you are actually using though), but I only got one trigger of the FuelChanged event (index of subscribtions equals 1), followed by the FuelFull event (index of subscribtions equals 0) and then the FuelNoLongerEmpty event which fails the test.

So I must have something different in my eventhandler code.

AFAIK, Lambda expressions are by definition lazily evaluated so they will not be evaluated until actually called and it compiles down to the same thing as using delegate syntax.

Comment: It is indeed NUnit, I'm confused that you got differing results to me, I'll have a look at my code and see if I made any errors in copying it into the question.

Comment: Well first, I needed to change your original code within the example of your public static void ExpectEventSequence, as subscription was unknown. I therefore used your last for loop.

Besides that, it would be good to know what your eventhandlers (or it's base when you use that) are. I am using NUnit 2.6.4. If possible you might add up a bit more code to your example (without revealing to much classified information :))

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'm not at my codebase until tomorrow but will give them both a look and see if I can reproduce your results. If not, I'll post the full code, just in case it's in how I'm raising events or something.

Comment: We'll await that then!

Comment: I have updated the code to include FuelTank, even by copy-pasting both answers' code into my project and commenting out my code I got the same results. Would the fact that I'm using Mono 2.0 (roughly .NET 3.5) have an effect on this?

Comment: I haven't used Mono yet, so I'll try to install that. I'll first update my code so that it matches yours and see what the differences are within the fired queue. I don't think that there are differences with Lambda's between .NET 3.5 and 4.5, but I need to look into that first. Others might have a quicker answer on that matter.

Comment: What exactly is your setup ? Are you using VS mono integration like described in [this link](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/visual_studio_integration/) ?

Comment: I'm using Unity3D's engine (which is running Mono 2.6 it turns out after a quick check) and Microsoft's Visual Studio Tools for Unity to integrate them.

Comment: I've updated my answer, the way you work with the queue's may cause the issue you are describing. I've missed that first (quite silly), but I guess this will help you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the following implementation based upon Nick's question.

First the class for the FuelTank:

```
public class FuelTank
{
    private float fuel;

    //Basic classes for the event handling, could be done by providing a few simple delegates,
    //but this is just to stick as close to the original question as possible.
    public FuelChanged FuelChanged = new FuelChanged();
    public FuelEmpty FuelEmpty = new FuelEmpty();
    public FuelFull FuelFull = new FuelFull();
    public FuelNoLongerEmpty FuelNoLongerEmpty = new FuelNoLongerEmpty();
    public FuelNoLongerFull FuelNoLongerFull = new FuelNoLongerFull();


    public float MaxFuel { get; set; }

    public float Fuel
    {
        get
        {
            return fuel;
        }
        private set
        {
            var adjustedFuel = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(value, MaxFuel));

            if (fuel != adjustedFuel)
            {
                var oldFuel = fuel;

                fuel = adjustedFuel;

                RaiseCheckFuelChangedEvents(oldFuel);
            }
        }
    }

    public void FillFuel()
    {
        Fuel = MaxFuel;
    }

    private void RaiseCheckFuelChangedEvents(float oldFuel)
    {
        FuelChanged.FireEvent(this, new FuelEventArgs(oldFuel, Fuel));

        if (fuel == 0)
        {
            FuelEmpty.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else if (fuel == MaxFuel)
        {
            FuelFull.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        if (oldFuel == 0 && Fuel != 0)
        {
            FuelNoLongerEmpty.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else if (oldFuel == MaxFuel && Fuel != MaxFuel)
        {
            FuelNoLongerFull.FireEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }      
}
```

As the code for the event handlers was missing, I made an assumption to use this. As the comment describes in the previous code block, it could be done more easily with plain delegates. It's just a matter of choice, for which I think this implementation isn't the best yet, but suitable enough for debugging:

```
public class FuelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private float oldFuel, newFuel;

    public FuelEventArgs(float oldFuel, float newFuel)
    {
        this.oldFuel = oldFuel;
        this.newFuel = newFuel;
    }
}

public class FuelEvents
{      
    public event EventHandler FireEventHandler;

    public virtual void FireEvent(object sender, EventArgs fuelArgs)
    {
        EventHandler handler = FireEventHandler;
        if (null != handler)
            handler(this, fuelArgs);
    }

}

public class FuelChanged : FuelEvents
{             

    public override void FireEvent(object sender, EventArgs fuelArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fired FuelChanged");
        base.FireEvent(sender, fuelArgs);
    }
}

public class FuelEmpty : FuelEvents
{
    public override void FireEvent(object sender, EventArgs fuelArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fired FuelEmpty");
        base.FireEvent(sender, fuelArgs);
    }
}

public class FuelFull : FuelEvents
{
    public override void FireEvent(object sender, EventArgs fuelArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fired FuelFull");
        base.FireEvent(sender, fuelArgs);
    }
}

public class FuelNoLongerEmpty : FuelEvents
{
    public override void FireEvent(object sender, EventArgs fuelArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fired FuelNoLongerEmpty");
        base.FireEvent(sender, fuelArgs);
    }
}

public class FuelNoLongerFull : FuelEvents
{
    public override void FireEvent(object sender, EventArgs fuelArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fired FuelNoLongerFull");
        base.FireEvent(sender, fuelArgs);
    }
}
```

And to test it all, I used this class, containing most code from the original question:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    public static void ExpectEventSequence(Queue<Action<EventHandler>> subscribeActions, Action triggerAction)
    {
        var expectedSequence = new Queue<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < subscribeActions.Count; i++)
        {
            expectedSequence.Enqueue(i);
        }

        ExpectEventSequence(subscribeActions, triggerAction, expectedSequence);
    }

    public static void ExpectEventSequence(Queue<Action<EventHandler>> subscribeActions, Action triggerAction, Queue<int> expectedSequence)
    {
        var fired = new Queue<int>();
        var actionsCount = subscribeActions.Count;

        //This code has been commented out due to the fact that subscription is unknown here.
        //I stuck to use the last solution that Nick provided himself

        //for (var i = 0; i < actionsCount; i++)
        //{
        //    subscription((o, e) =>
        //    {
        //        fired.Enqueue(i);
        //    });
        //}

        var subscriptions = subscribeActions.ToList();

        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            subscription((o, e) =>
            {
                var index = subscriptions.IndexOf(subscription);
                Console.WriteLine("[ExpectEventSequence] Found index: {0}", index);
                fired.Enqueue(index);
            });
        }

        triggerAction();

        var executionIndex = 0;

        var inOrder = true;

        foreach (var firedIndex in fired)
        {

            if (firedIndex != expectedSequence.Dequeue())
            {
                inOrder = false;
                break;
            }

            executionIndex++;
            Console.WriteLine("Execution index: {0}", executionIndex);
        }

        if (subscribeActions.Count != fired.Count)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Not all events were fired.");
        }

        if (!inOrder)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Contents of Fired Queue: {0}", PrintValues(fired));

            Assert.Fail(string.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                "Events were not fired in the expected sequence from element {0}",
                executionIndex));

        }
    }

    private static string PrintValues(Queue<int> myCollection)
    {
        return string.Format( "{{0}}", string.Join(",", myCollection.ToArray()));

    }


    [Test()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]
    public void FillFuel_Test([Values(1, 5, 10, 100)]float maxFuel)
    {  

        var fuelTank = new FuelTank()
        {
            MaxFuel = maxFuel
        };

        var eventHandlerSequence = new Queue<Action<EventHandler>>();

        eventHandlerSequence.Enqueue(x => fuelTank.FuelFull.FireEventHandler += x);

        //Dealing with a subclass of EventHandler
        eventHandlerSequence.Enqueue(x => fuelTank.FuelChanged.FireEventHandler += (o, e) => x(o, e));

        ExpectEventSequence(eventHandlerSequence, () => fuelTank.FillFuel());
    }
}
```

Now, when running the tests with NUnit, I noticed the following results:

The first event that got triggered was the **FuelChanged** event, this causes the fired queue within the method

```
public static void ExpectEventSequence(Queue<Action<EventHandler>> subscribeActions, Action triggerAction, Queue<int> expectedSequence)
```

to contain {1}.

The next event that triggers is the **FuelFull** event, which means that the fired queue now contains:
{1,0} as expected according to the question of Nick.

The last event that triggers is the **FuelNoLongerEmpty** event and this one fails the test.

***Note:***
As this code does not yet provide an answer to the original question of the fact that lambda's might cause some interference, as the code I provided above, does just the right thing.

The following rules apply to variable scope in lambda expressions:

- A variable that is captured will not be garbage-collected until the
  delegate that references it goes out of scope.
- Variables introduced within a lambda expression are not visible in
  the outer method.
- A lambda expression cannot directly capture a ref or out parameter
  from an enclosing method.
- A return statement in a lambda expression does not cause the
  enclosing method to return.
- A lambda expression cannot contain a goto statement, break statement,
  or continue statement whose target is outside the body or in the body
  of a contained anonymous function.

So the problem in Nick's original question might be caused by the fact that you enumerate over a queue. While enumerating and passing these directly to a lambda expression, you will work with a reference. A trick might be to actually de-reference it by copying it to a local variable within the scope of the iteration loop. This is exactly what *smiech* is referring to in his post.

**EDIT:**

I've just looked into it again for you. Are you sure the 'challenge' that you are having is not just the fact that comparing the fired dictionary's indices to the expectedSequence.Dequeue is happening in reversed order? Please note that queue's are FIFO based, so when dequeueing, it will retrieve the first that is inserted...

I noticed that (according to my code) the fired dictionary contains {1,0} whereas the expectedSequence dictionary contains {0,1}. By looking at the expected events, this is good for the expectedSequence queue. So actually the fired queue (filled within your last code block) is built up incorrectly by means of the 'age' of the eventhandler.

When I change one statement within the code that you provided in the original

```
 public static void ExpectEventSequence(Queue<Action<EventHandler>> subscribeActions, Action triggerAction, Queue<int> expectedSequence)
```

method from

```
  var subscriptions = subscribeActions.ToList();

  foreach (var firedIndex in fired)
  {

    if (firedIndex != expectedSequence.Dequeue())
    {
       inOrder = false;
       break;
    }

    executionIndex++;
    Console.WriteLine("Execution index: {0}", executionIndex);
  }
```

to this:

```
   //When comparing indexes, you'll probably need to reverse the fired queue
   fired = new Queue<int>(fired.Reverse());
   foreach (var firedIndex in fired)
   {

     if (firedIndex != expectedSequence.Dequeue())
     {
       inOrder = false;
       break;
     }

     executionIndex++;
     Console.WriteLine("Execution index: {0}", executionIndex);
   }
```

then everything in your test will pass flawlessly, as you can see with this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: For me, the `fired` indices contains {1,1}. Although you are right that this is another bug I had not foreseen, and I shall use `.Reverse()` in my code.

Comment: Hi @NickUdell, do you happen to have some output from NUnit?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to run inside a wrapper in Unity that doesn't give much info. I'll try extracting the code from any Unity libraries and running it in its own solution.

Comment: That would be a good approach. If that is put within a Visual Studio approach and if you have troubles still, let me know. I can't really let this pass by unless we both know what the heck is going on.

Comment: Extracted the code into its own visual studio project and the tests now run as expected. I'm going to have to chalk this one up to Unity's visual studio bridge and submit a bug report.

Comment: @NickUdell, now that explained what was wrong. I do hope you can find a proper workaround for your project!

Answer (score 2):

for the first part: yes, it had to do with the way lambdas variable scope. See [Access to Modified Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure). 
Because I spent some time trying to figure it out, I allow myself to paste the code I've used (all tests passing).

```
class Test
{
    public static void ExpectEventSequence(Queue<Action<EventHandler>> subscribeActions, Action triggerAction)
    {
        var expectedSequence = new Queue<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < subscribeActions.Count; i++)
            expectedSequence.Enqueue(i);
        ExpectEventSequence(subscribeActions, triggerAction, expectedSequence);
    }

    public static void ExpectEventSequence(Queue<Action<EventHandler>> subscribeActions, Action triggerAction, Queue<int> expectedSequence)
    {
        var fired = new Queue<int>();
        var subscriptions = subscribeActions.ToList();

        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            subscription((o, e) =>
            {
                var index = subscriptions.IndexOf(subscription);
                fired.Enqueue(index);
            });
        }
        triggerAction();
        var executionIndex = 0;
        var inOrder = true;
        foreach (var firedIndex in fired)
        {
            if (firedIndex != expectedSequence.Dequeue())
            {
                inOrder = false;
                break;
            }
            executionIndex++;
        }
        if (subscribeActions.Count != fired.Count)
            Assert.Fail("Not all events were fired.");
        if (!inOrder)
            Assert
                .Fail(string.Format(
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                "Events were not fired in the expected sequence from element {0}",
                executionIndex));
    }
}

public class Fueled
{
    public event EventHandler<FuelEventArgs> FuelChanged = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler FuelEmpty = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler FuelFull = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler FuelNoLongerFull = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler FuelNoLongerEmpty = delegate { };
    private float fuel;

    public float Fuel
    {
        get{ return fuel; }
        private set
        {
            var adjustedFuel = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(value, MaxFuel));

            if (fuel != adjustedFuel)
            {
                var oldFuel = fuel;
                fuel = adjustedFuel;
                RaiseCheckFuelChangedEvents(oldFuel);
            }
        }
    }

    public void FillFuel()
    {
        Fuel = MaxFuel;
    }

    public float MaxFuel { get; set; }

    private void RaiseCheckFuelChangedEvents(float oldFuel)
    {
        FuelChanged(this, new FuelEventArgs(oldFuel, Fuel));

        if (fuel == 0)
            FuelEmpty(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        else if (fuel == MaxFuel)
            FuelFull(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        if (oldFuel == 0 && Fuel != 0)
            FuelNoLongerEmpty(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        else if (oldFuel == MaxFuel && Fuel != MaxFuel)
            FuelNoLongerFull(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class FuelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public FuelEventArgs(float oldFuel, float fuel)
    {
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test()]
    public void FillFuel_Test([Values(1, 5, 10, 100)]float maxFuel)
    {
        var fuelTank = new Fueled()
        {
            MaxFuel = maxFuel
        };
        var eventHandlerSequence = new Queue<Action<EventHandler>>();
        //Dealing with a subclass of EventHandler
        eventHandlerSequence.Enqueue(x => fuelTank.FuelChanged += (o, e) => x(o, e));
        eventHandlerSequence.Enqueue(x => fuelTank.FuelFull += x);
        Test.ExpectEventSequence(eventHandlerSequence, () => fuelTank.FillFuel());
    }
}
```

Basically I've only changed the order of expected events in test method. If you are still getting incorrect results after changing the loop  I think the problem must be outside of your pasted code scope. I'm using VS 2013 community + resharper 8 , nunit 2.6.4.14350

**Edit: different approach**

I was trying to solve the problem you actually posted, but maybe this will actually be what you want:
wouldn't you consider trying a simplified version of your approach?:

```
[Test()]
public void FillFuel_Test([Values(1, 5, 10, 100)]float maxFuel)
{
    var fuelTank = new Fueled()
    {
        MaxFuel = maxFuel
    };
    var expectedEventSequence = new[]
    {
        "FuelChanged",
        "FuelFull"
    };
    var triggeredEventSequence = new List<string>();
    fuelTank.FuelChanged += (o, e) => triggeredEventSequence.Add("FuelChanged");
    fuelTank.FuelFull += (o, e) => triggeredEventSequence.Add("FuelFull");

    fuelTank.FillFuel();

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedEventSequence,triggeredEventSequence);
}
```