# LINQ | ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
for (int i = 0; i < intFeatureIDs.Count; i++) {
    slots_for = slots_for.Where(s => s.featureSlotMapping.Any(fsm => fsm.featureID == intFeatureIDs[i]));
}
```

Here, intFeatureID.Count is 2. And throws below exception.

## Exception:

Message=An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. To show additional information call EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring.

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

If intFeatureIDs.Count == 1, there is no issue.

Also, If I comment out the for loop, and manually run the code twice, it will work...

```
slots = slots.Where(s => s.featureSlotMapping.Any(fsm => fsm.featureID == intFeatureIDs[1]));
slots = slots.Where(s => s.featureSlotMapping.Any(fsm => fsm.featureID == intFeatureIDs[2]));
```

Any comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Hi mjwills, thanks for your prompt response. But slots_for is type IQueryable<Slots>, and toTlist() returns List<Slots>... it won't work...

Comment: That's the end of intFeatureIDs... I don't have any other code touching this variable anymore...

Comment: Will the delay evaluation of LINQ ignore the variable in for loop? Is that what you implied?

Comment: checking, one moment.

Comment: You are the man!!! I got it, "i" is only visible within the for loop. When delayed, the value is lost.  Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing the code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < intFeatureIDs.Count; i++) {
    var bob = intFeatureIDs[i];
    slots_for = slots_for.Where(s => s.featureSlotMapping.Any(fsm => fsm.featureID == bob));
}
```

This fixes the [modified closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235459/34092) issue in your code, and potentially insulates your code against other code (not shown in your sample) that may change / reassign `intFeatureIDs`.