# Generate List<Task> with using index in for like parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, parallel-processing, task

I want to generate `List<Task>` and then call it all parallel. I try to do this, but not understood how pass index in lambda expression. In my realisation always send last index of `for`. But i want to use all indexes in parallel computing...

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

var  valueSize = Values.Count;
for (int i = 1; i <= valueSize; i++)
{
   tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(
   () => {
      this.Values[i] = this._tcpRepository.GetValueAsync(i).ToString().GetInt32();
   }));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Additional information:

`public Dictionary<int, int> Values { get; set; }`

In TcpRepository

```
public async Task<string> GetValueAsync(int digit)
{
   var netStream = this.TcpClient.GetStream();
   if (netStream.CanWrite)
   {
      Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(digit.ToString());
      await netStream.WriteAsync(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
   }
   if (netStream.CanRead)
   {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[this.Client.ReceiveBufferSize];

      await netStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int)this.Client.ReceiveBufferSize);
      return bytes.ToString();
   }
   return null;
}
```

`GetInt32()` it's my custom extension for string `public static int GetInt32(this string value)`. Strings can come with garbage as characters that are not numbers.

Comment: Do `int iCopy = i;` and pass `iCopy` to the lambda. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure

Comment: Also `this._tcpRepository.GetValueAsync(i).ToString()` looks a bit suspicious. I don't think this will act as you like it to act. This will return the string representation of the `Task<string>` object. Not the result of the method.  Instead use this: `(await this._tcpRepository.GetValueAsync(i)).GetInt32();` to get the result returned by the method.

Comment: Related: [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

To directly answer your question, you need to create a closure over `i` to prevent it being updated before it is accessed in your async code.

You can do this by swapping your `for` loop with `Enumerable.Range`.

Another issue is that you are running `GetValueAsync` on the ThreadPool but not awaiting it. Subsequently, your `Task.WaitAll` will be waiting for the outer `Task`s only, not the `Task`s returned by `GetValueAsync`.

Here is an example of what you could do:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, valueSize)
    .Select(async i =>
    {
        string val = await _tcpRepository.GetValueAsync(i);
        Values[i] = val.GetInt32();
    });
```

Your final issue is the use of `Task.WaitAll`; this introduces the sync-over-async antipattern. You should allow async to grow through your code base, and instead use `Task.WhenAll`, which returns a `Task` that completes when all the provided `Task`s are complete:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```