# How to use the array of checkbox in ASP.NET Core Razor?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

```
@for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="values[i]" />
}
```

```
@code {
    private List<bool> values = new List<bool>() { true, true, false };
}
```

Why did the following exception occur when I clicked the "checkbox" generated by the above code?

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

What is the right way? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of C# behaviour.
You can use a foreach loop or capture the variable.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    var iCopy = i;
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="values[iCopy]" />
}
```

Comment: I like your iCopy more. :). A more descriptive name than temp.

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop you iterate over `i`. In each iteration, the value of `i` is increased by one. The value is not bound to let's say `values[1]` but to `values[i]` which is after the last iteration 3 for each element. 3 violates the array boundaries, hence the exception.

> The underlying reason is that a lambda expression is used to make this binding. In this lambda expression `i` is not a value, but a reference. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235455/access-to-modified-closure/235459#235459) for a similar example.

To prevent it, add a new variable inside the for loop to save the current value of `i`.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    var temp = i;
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="values[temp]" />
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very detailed, it is very enlightening for me to solve other problems. Thanks ^_^